# tkinter can't add photo in class that not include mainloop

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm not familiar with python and specially with GUI issues.
I'm trying to add image from other class, I found a way to add other object but not images.
This code work fine:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.parent = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.outputBox = Text(self.parent, bg='black', height= 10, fg='green', relief=SUNKEN, yscrollcommand='TRUE')
        self.outputBox.pack(fill='both', expand=True)



def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.parent.geometry('800x500')
    app.parent.configure(background = 'red')
    path = "../img/Stalin.jpeg"
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    panel = Label(app.parent, image = img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")  
    app.mainloop()

main()
```

But when I try to add image from class it's open the window but without the image:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.parent = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.outputBox = Text(self.parent, bg='black', height= 10, fg='green', relief=SUNKEN, yscrollcommand='TRUE')
        self.outputBox.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        path = "../img/Stalin.jpeg"
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        panel = Label(self.parent, image = img)
        panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")  

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.parent.geometry('800x500')
    app.parent.configure(background = 'red')
    app.mainloop()

main()
```

working with python 2.7 on eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given [here -](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)

> You can use the label to display PhotoImage and BitmapImage objects. **When doing this, make sure you keep a reference to the image object, to prevent it from being garbage collected by Python’s memory allocator.**  You can use a global variable or an instance attribute.

(Emphasis mine)

But in your second example, the image object `img` is a local variable in `initUI()` method, hence when the method ends the image gets garbage collected (especially in CPython, since it uses reference counting) . You should store the image as an instance attribute -

```
def initUI(self):
    self.outputBox = Text(self.parent, bg='black', height= 10, fg='green', relief=SUNKEN, yscrollcommand='TRUE')
    self.outputBox.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    path = "../img/Stalin.jpeg"
    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    panel = Label(self.parent, image = self.img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
```

---

It works in your first case, because you enter the `mainloop` from `main()` method, hence the `main()` method does not end until the `mainloop()` ends, and hence the image does not get garbage collected until the application quits.

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have thought of garbage collection being an issue.